# Button values disappear when changing javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Currently I have a working app that could change the values of the buttons depending on the button clicked. It is written using javascript (in `script.js`). However I want to make it nicer so i am trying to use jQuery instead. However, when i insert the jQuery js and css file to `index.html`, the buttons' values are gone and i don't know how to change it completely to jQuery without affecting its function.

here is part of the original javascript: (let me know if you want to see the whole script)

```
ajax_status.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if(ajax_status.readyState == 4 && ajax_status.status == 200) {

if(ajax_status.responseText == "ready_vid") {

  document.getElementById("video_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("video_button").value = "record video start";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ca 1");};
  document.getElementById("image_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("image_button").value = "record image";
  document.getElementById("image_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("im");};
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").value = "timelapse start";
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("tl " + (document.getElementById("tl_interval").value*10));};
  document.getElementById("md_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("md_button").value = "motion detection start";
  document.getElementById("md_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("md 1");};
  document.getElementById("halt_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("halt_button").value = "stop camera";
  document.getElementById("halt_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ru 0");};
  document.getElementById("mode_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("mode_button").value = "change mode to image";
  document.getElementById("mode_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("pm");};
  halted = 0;
}
else if(ajax_status.responseText == "ready_img") {
  document.getElementById("video_button").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("video_button").value = "record video start";
  document.getElementById("video_button").onclick = function() {};
  document.getElementById("image_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("image_button").value = "record image";
  document.getElementById("image_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("im");};
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").value = "timelapse start";
  document.getElementById("timelapse_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("tl " + (document.getElementById("tl_interval").value*10));};
  document.getElementById("md_button").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("md_button").value = "motion detection start";
  document.getElementById("md_button").onclick = function() {};
  document.getElementById("halt_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("halt_button").value = "stop camera";
  document.getElementById("halt_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("ru 0");};
  document.getElementById("mode_button").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("mode_button").value = "change mode to video";
  document.getElementById("mode_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("vm");};
  halted = 0;
}
```

HTML in index.html:

```
<input id="video_button" type="button">
<!--<button data-role="none" id="video_button"></button>
<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" id="image_button"></button> //this is wad i tried-->
  <input id="image_button" type="button">
  <input id="timelapse_button" type="button">
  <input id="md_button" type="button"><br>
  <input id="halt_button" type="button">
  <input id="mode_button" type="button">
```

I have some other jQuery scripts in index.html. The above javascript in in another file called `script.js`. My question is, do i also insert the link for jQuery.js in that script.js? And how about `$(document).ready(function()`? Do i put it in the script.js too?

Comment: What is the jquery code you are trying to use? And you include jquery.js like you would script.js, but you have to include it before the script.js or whatever other file you use the jquery code in.

Comment: Yes i include this in `index.html` as such `<script src="static/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="static/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
 <script src="script.js"></script>` My question is whether to include the jQuery files in `script.js` too?

Comment: no, you do not need to include the jquery files in the script.js.  In you script.js, you should wrap your javascript(jquery) functionality in a `$document.ready(function() {});`.  In order to keep the verbosity of your `$document.ready(fundtion() {});` down, you can just call functions that are defined outside of it from within it.

Answer (score 0):

For minimal change you can do following,

1. include the jquery library in  tag as 
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
2. replace document.getElementById('id') to $('#id').

   document.getElementById("video_button") => $('#video_button')
3. Anything after the document.getElementById() get bit different in jquery

   document.getElementById("video_button").disabled = false;
   $('#video_button').removeAttr('disabled');

   document.getElementById("video_button").value = "record video start";
   $('#video_button').val('record video start');

   document.getElementById("image_button").onclick = function() {send_cmd("im");};
   $('#image_button').click(function() {send_cmd("im");});

references

- https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
- http://api.jquery.com/val
- http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: thanks! for your first point (include jquery library), do u mean to include it in `index.html` or `script.js`?

Comment: include it in index.html. The syntax listed in point 1 would only work in html anyway.

Comment: For `document.getElementById("video_button").disabled = false; $('#video_button').removeAttr('disabled');` , how about if `disabled = true`?